# Multiple lights points on single 3d model with different colours of lights shades in Metal iOS

Tags: 3d, swift3, sprite-kit, scenekit, metal

I want to put Multiple lights points on single 3d model with different colours of lights shades in metal IOS.

I have gone through the this assignment [IOS - Metal](http://metalbyexample.com/up-and-running-3/#comment-10142)

Now, I want to apply multiple lights points with different colour in a single 3d model.

[image]
Look at the attached image(Developed in SceneKit and SpriteKit -SKLightNode), Similar lights refection effect need on 3D model.

Comment: I think it can be done using SceneKit of iOS instead of Metal.

Comment: Metal provides the lowest-overhead access to the GPU. Its a brand new technology from Apple.

Answer (score 3):

The essential thing to realize is that the light that reflects from a surface is *additive*: each light will contribute some amount of irradiance, and the radiant exitance of the surface is the sum of the surface's response to this energy. The quantities we will use are still not fully physically-based, but this insight will help us select values that don't blow out the final color too badly.

For the sake of simplicity, we'll stick to directional lights. You could easily generalize this to point or spot lights; it's just a matter of passing in the properties you need and computing the per-light contributions.

First, remove the definition of `struct Light` and the global `light` value. We'll be hoisting these into the uniforms struct so we can set them from application code.

Redefine the `Light` struct in the "Shared.h" header so it can be seen from both our Objective-C and Metal code:

```
#define kMaxLights 4

typedef struct
{
    vector_float3 direction;
    vector_float3 ambientColor;
    vector_float3 diffuseColor;
    vector_float3 specularColor;
} Light;
```

While we're at it, let's switch from using the `simd` namespace to using the `vector_` and `matrix_` prefixes, just to reduce our dependence on Objective-C++:

```
typedef struct
{
    matrix_float4x4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
    matrix_float4x4 modelViewMatrix;
    matrix_float3x3 normalMatrix;
    Light lights [kMaxLights];
} Uniforms;
```

Here, we're including a fixed-size array of lights in our uniforms struct so we can specify up to four lights without branching in our shader. You can decrease or increase this number as necessary.

Over in application code (specifically, the `updateUniforms` method), we can redefine the first light to match the previous values:

```
Uniforms uniforms = { 0 };
```

(to zero-out the uniforms struct, and then)

```
uniforms.lights[0].direction = (vector_float3){ 0.13, 0.72, 0.68 };
uniforms.lights[0].ambientColor = (vector_float3){ 0.05, 0.05, 0.05 };
uniforms.lights[0].diffuseColor = (vector_float3){ 0.9, 0.9, 0.9 };
uniforms.lights[0].specularColor = (vector_float3){ 1, 1, 1 };
```

You can now run the app to see the same results as before, with the advantage that the light properties are now programmable instead of being hard-coded.

At this point, I'm going to switch over to a white, shiny surface material by setting both ambient and diffuse response to white in the shader code:

```
constant Material material = {
    .ambientColor = { 1, 1, 1 },
    .diffuseColor = { 1, 1, 1 },
    .specularColor = { 1, 1, 1 },
    .specularPower = 100
};
```

Let's modify our shader to loop over the various lights, remembering to normalize the light direction wherever we encounter it, so we don't get excessive contributions:

```
fragment float4 fragment_main(ProjectedVertex vert [[stage_in]],
                              constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(0)]])
{
    float3 color(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < kMaxLights; ++i) {
        constant Light *light = &uniforms.lights[i];
        float3 ambientTerm = light->ambientColor * material.ambientColor;

        float3 normal = normalize(vert.normal);
        float diffuseIntensity = saturate(dot(normal, normalize(light->direction)));
        float3 diffuseTerm = light->diffuseColor * material.diffuseColor * diffuseIntensity;

        float3 specularTerm(0);
        if (diffuseIntensity > 0)
        {
            float3 eyeDirection = normalize(vert.eye);
            float3 halfway = normalize(normalize(light->direction) + eyeDirection);
            float specularFactor = pow(saturate(dot(normal, halfway)), material.specularPower);
            specularTerm = light->specularColor * material.specularColor * specularFactor;
        }

        color += ambientTerm + diffuseTerm + specularTerm;
    }

    return float4(color, 1);
}
```

Now we can define the properties of all four lights, back in the `updateUniforms` method:

```
uniforms.lights[0].direction = (vector_float3){ -1, 1, 1 };
uniforms.lights[0].ambientColor = (vector_float3){ 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 };
uniforms.lights[0].diffuseColor = (vector_float3){ 0.7, 0, 0 };
uniforms.lights[0].specularColor = (vector_float3){ 0.15, 0.15, 0.15 };

uniforms.lights[1].direction = (vector_float3){ 1, 1, 1 };
uniforms.lights[1].ambientColor = (vector_float3){ 0 };
uniforms.lights[1].diffuseColor = (vector_float3){ 0, 0.4, 0 };
uniforms.lights[1].specularColor = (vector_float3){ 0.15, 0.15, 0.15 };

uniforms.lights[2].direction = (vector_float3){ -1, -1, 1 };
uniforms.lights[2].ambientColor = (vector_float3){ 0 };
uniforms.lights[2].diffuseColor = (vector_float3){ 0, 0, 0.7 };
uniforms.lights[2].specularColor = (vector_float3){ 0.15, 0.15, 0.15 };

uniforms.lights[3].direction = (vector_float3){ 1, 1, 1 };
uniforms.lights[3].ambientColor = (vector_float3){ 0 };
uniforms.lights[3].diffuseColor = (vector_float3){ 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 };
uniforms.lights[3].specularColor = (vector_float3){ 0.15, 0.15, 0.15 };
```

And here's the result, a white teapot lit from several different directions by lights with different properties:

[image: Multicolored teapot]

Comment: Good one!, Thanks for your nice explanation.

Comment: Actually, Given solution is good. but it was changed the textured property of model. What I need exactly, I want to add lights effect on 3d model without change actual property, I have done in 2d graphics using scenekit and SpriteKit (SKLightNode) - Please look in attached image.

Comment: SceneKit - Can we use multiple lights on single model? Each of lights shades want different colour, It should be look like attached above image in question.

Comment: I believe you can only have one `SCNLight` per `SCNNode`, but you can add as many nodes as you want to your scene.

Comment: yes, I am adding multiple nodes for different types of light colours (direction light), but thing is i am not able to change its position on scene. I have try two property for that position & physicsBody.

Comment: I don't want to allow camera Control. 3D object is steady on screen and want to move lights around it by touch move or gesture.